# Database Exception Could not find driver when connecting from PHP to MSSQL database on Mac / Unix system

Tags: php, sql-server, unix, pdo

First of all, I have tried searching through a lot of the same questions, but many of them are outdated or did not provide the results I need.

On my local machine, when running `php -m`, I get

```
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
```

When I run
`echo "<h1>PDO drivers</h1><pre>", print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()), "</pre>";` in a PHP file, I get

```
PDO drivers
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
    [2] => pgsql
)
```

I have tried a lot of different drivers, but I found that it's best to use dblib for non-windows systems.

I open a connection with following code:

```
use yii\db\Connection;

$connection = new Connection([
            //-> THIS ONE WORKS FOR MYSQL
            //'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=<testdb>;host=<testhost>;port=<port>', 

            //-> THIS ONE I'M TRYING TO GET WORKING
            'dsn' => 'dblib:host=<windows MSSQL Server via tcp>;dbname=<db>',
            'username' => '<user>',
            'password' => '<pass>'
        ]);

        $connection->open();
```

What do I need to do locally to get this running on my machine? I am running MAMP Pro.

I am a bit worried, because this PHP server is running on a Unix system and I will need to be able to get it working there as well.

Comment: Why not use the [official drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: That you get `pdo_dblib` in your CLI output but not in your page output suggests your server has different `php.ini` files for each, and the latter simply doesn't load the module you want. You can use `phpinfo()` to find which config file is being loaded, and make sure the module is enabled there.

Comment: Considering this is Unix based, `php -m` is likely looking at `./cli/php.ini` where as Apache is using `./apache2/php.ini` (where `.` is the install location for PHP, which can varu based on the distro you are using).

Comment: @AlexHowansky the module does not seem to be present in phpinfo().
How would I go on about installing it?

Comment: You have to add `extension = whatever` to the appropriate INI file and then restart your web server process.

Comment: @Larnu I am looking into them. Hopefully they're easy to install on Ubuntu systems as well.

Comment: On Ubuntu it would be `/etc/php/{version}/apache2/php.ini`